# Expected value of function of normal variable

Tags: probability

Given that X is normal with mean 2 and variance 1, a book I have says that

$$
 E[100e^X]=100E[e^X]=100e^2E[e^{Xs}]=100e^{5/2}
$$

I have a feeling that there is a mistake the $ e^2 $ should be an $e^{-2}$ correct me if I am wrong. Next, I am completely clueless as to how we go from the 3rd equation to the fourth equation.

Comment: If $X$ is normal with mean $2$ and variance $1$ then $X=X_0+2$ where $X_0$ is *standard* normal (mean $0$ and variance $1$), thus $$E(100e^X)=100E(e^{X_0+2})=100e^2E(e^{X_0})$$ and the value of $E(e^{tX_0})$ for every $t$ should be in your bag of known identities if it is not already...

Answer (score 1):

The moment generating function of a normal random variable $X$  is
$$
E(e^{tX})=\exp\left(\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2\right)
$$
so $E(e^X)=\exp(\mu+(\sigma^2/2))=\exp(5/2)$. In particular,
$$
E(100e^X)=100E(e^X)=100e^{5/2}.
$$

Comment: so in the 3rd equation why is there an $ e^2$ thanks very much

Comment: I guess they factored out $e^2$ to standardize the normal random variable to $X-2$ or as they say $Xs$

Comment: Yeah, then why is it $e^2 $and not $ e^{-2}$. thanks